# The possible element orders of $S_{7}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Show that the possible orders of the elements of group $S_{7}$ part of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,12\}$

Comment: I need suggestions for this question. I do not know if there is a direct way to show that the order of the permutations that are in $ S_ {7} $ belong to the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,12\}$. Or necessarily I have to express the permutations in disjoint cycles and calculate their orders from each one.

Answer (score 2):

The possible orders of an element in $S_7$ are least common multiples of the numbers in partitions of $7$. This is because the order of $\sigma\in S_7$ is equal to the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles in its disjoint cycle decomposition.

Comment: necessarily I have to express the permutations in disjoint cycles and calculate their orders from each one??

Comment: There are fifteen partitions of $7$, so you just have to examine these fifteen cases.